# Is there no double post detector on SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I have done some reviewing task.

I came across this 2 answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339365/2441442
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339423/2441442

These 2 answers on the same question are written by the same author. Also the content of the answer is byte by byte the same (at least at the initial version of both).

I have flagged it with moderators attention "Doublepost". I hope this was the right decission.

Is there no system in Background, which would detect them automaticly?

Comment: I have downvoted and voted to delete one of the posts. Also flagged as VLQ, since it isn't recoverable and should be deleted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two posts had some... minor differences in formatting, which made the system think these were *not* double posts. The system is only able to detect and flag *exact* character-for-character duplicate answers.

Compare the following excerpts from the original revision of each answer:

```
Copy this block...
colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion"..../colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion"
and
colorGroup doctypes="CSS" .... /colorGroup doctypes="CSS"
```

And:

```
Copy this block
<colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion">....</colorGroup doctypes="ColdFusion">
and
<colorGroup doctypes="CSS"> .... </colorGroup doctypes="CSS"
```

It looks like the user was trying to edit their original post, but instead submitted it as a new one.

Comment: In other words there's a `PostHash` column in the `Posts` table that holds a checksum (for instance) of the post and a dupe check when the `Posts` table is altered, but no unique index on this column.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sence. Didn't see this missing `<`, `>` in detail. :)

Comment: `The system is only able to...` please, does SE not employ the best engineers available?

Comment: It's not google which does contextual analasys of documents to see if it's about the same thing :P

Comment: @digitgopher Yes, and SE probably chooses not to waste their time on something like this, which is clearly not a major problem on the site.

Comment: @digitgopher: Yeah but they're all busy working on Tamagotchis and TV channels :)

Comment: I've seen something happen to me that's led to a double posting during editing.  Some kind of `ajax` glitch I guess, and when the page was refreshed, it was revealed that my edit had been posted as another answer.  I'm not saying that's what happened here, but it may be more complex than the user intentionally posting a second answer instead of editing.

Answer (score 16):

It turns to be surprisingly easy to accidentally do this. If you click on or try to type at the preview instead of the edit box, you can find yourself editing a new answer. This has happened to me more than once, and I have never figured out quite how the old text ends up in the new answer.

Thanks to the comments, I think I can even supply the recipe:

1. click on the preview
2. hit backspace to delete something
3. edit and submit
4. slap self.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised. I've caught my self do that on accident once.

Comment: What do you mean, "click on or try to type at the preview"? Why would that magically copy the answer text?

Comment: The only thing that happend a few times to me is that I pressed the browser's `back` button instead of the post's `edit` button, then editing my answer, and then hitting `enter` resubmitted the answer instead of editing the existing one.

Comment: @Bergi: The 'edit' interface doesn't create a new entry in the browser history, so hitting the back button takes you all the way to the previous page; and in many browsers, the backspace key has the same effect as the back button. So I suppose what bmargulies is doing is accidentally/mistakenly clicking on the preview and hitting the backspace key (with the intent of deleting some text).

Comment: @ruakh: I didn't mean the "edit" interface but the "post an answer" interface, which does take you to a new page. And after going back, you might post your answer a second time accidently.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah, I understood that. Hence my reply. :-)